# Should I accept this offer?

Tags: relocation

Recently I've got a job offer to relocate from China to Antwerp(Belgium).

In gathering the information of Antwerp and Belgium, I came across the below worst violence problem.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.theguardian.com/world/2006/may/26/worlddispatch.nicholaswatt

So I'm worry about that should I accept this offer?

Comment: a 15 yr old news article ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dare to say you're safe...

One swallow does not a summer make. Sure, there are racial crimes that are across the world but it happens everywhere. If you're Uighur in China, you'll face it. If you're muslim in France, you'll face it. If you're white in Saudi Arabia, you'll face it.

More important is for you to build a personal safety plan. What will YOU do in the case of an emergency? Can you speak the language and get the authorities in a need situation? Europe is usually very good about providing public services, so if you know how to use them, you are probably ok. There is nowhere in the world that is totally safe from crime, but Belgium is quite modern and good, despite publicized stories to the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is a great forum to ask these questions, specially when you're straight up asking "should I accept this offer".

Anyway, I'd say, you will find incidents of this kind on any country on earth if you go back enough. You could maybe get a somewhat decent indicator based on crime indexes by city such as provided by Numbeo [here](https://www.numbeo.com/crime/region_rankings.jsp?region=150&title=2018).

As you may have no context in Europe to relate these values to I offer some anecdotal evidence: Porto which is roughly 20 ranks above Antwerp has been a very safe major tourist destination for years.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rephrase the question to make it more suitable for this site. For example making it a bit more generic about relocating (although there are probably already very good answers on the topic). I will however try to answer about.

*[Disclaimer]I'm a white heterosexual belgian man born and raised in Belgium[/Disclaimer]*

First of all, this event was a pretty much isolated event which is still remembered today. In general I wouldn't describe the overall country as being extremely discriminatory, Antwerp not being any kind of special on that. In addition, when there are indeed racial tensions (because I guess it happens everywhere), I think people from Africa are probably more often the target than Asian people. Antwerp is actually a rather cosmopolitan city.

In other words, should you be worried about your own security relocating in Antwerp (or anywhere in Belgium actually)? No, I don't think so. You may actually get even less trouble coming from China not speaking Dutch than myself coming from Wallonia (French-speaking part of Belgium) not speaking it very well...